# Restore Subscriber with a different DB Merge Replication

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, merge, replication, merge-replication

I have a Publisher and a Subscriber using pull subscription at Merge Replication. Let's say that the shared folder with the snapshot has 50GB size.
I have a scenario in mind that aims to minimize bandwidth during transmission.

Can I take a backup from a subscriber and use it to create a new DB as new subscriber one on a different server?

And if this is possible, is the server going to download the whole 50GB of the shared folder or because of the already existing data, will save some bandwidth?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this and this is one of the quickest ways.

For more information refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/initialize-a-transactional-subscription-without-a-snapshot

Comment: I am asking about Merge Replication not Transactional.